# Java 8 group by and BigDecimal

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, bigdecimal

I have a Java class like

```
public class A {
    private int id;
    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

I would like to group by id with java 8 several objects like this :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A(1, new BigDecimal("500.36"));
        A a2 = new A(2, new BigDecimal("439.97"));
        A a3 = new A(2, new BigDecimal("49.97"));
        A a4 = new A(2, new BigDecimal("9.97"));

        List<A> postings = new ArrayList<>();
        postings.add(a1);
        postings.add(a2);
        postings.add(a3);
        postings.add(a4);

        List<A> brol = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("-----------------");

        postings.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A -> A.getId(), Collectors.summingDouble(A->A.getAmount().doubleValue())))
                .forEach((id, sum) -> brol.add(new A(id, BigDecimal.valueOf(sum))));

        brol.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

And the output is :

> 1 500.36
>  2 499.91

Which is exactly what I'm looking for. But, there is the `Collectors.summingDouble` operation and I know that `Double` is not suitable for currency operations.
So will I have problems with this method (working on money operations) or there is a way to do it with BigDecimal ?

Comment: Please do not put answer in your question. Post it separately by pressing "Post your answer".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `reducing` to perform the summing with `BigDecimal`:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getId,              
                               Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, 
                                                   A::getAmount, 
                                                   BigDecimal::add)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for the same. Is this the only way, or we can do the same by some other way ?